# Jenkins debian building fails: rosdep claims that roscpp is not a system dependency

Tags: ros, jenkins, ros-groovy, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I am trying to release this following dry stack into ROS Groovy: http://svn.code.sf.net/p/bosch-ros-pkg/code/trunk/stacks/bosch_common/.

The build failed emails that I got from Jenkins state that " Error: package/stack 'rtc' depends on non-existent package 'roscpp' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'" (http://jenkins.willowgarage.com:8080/job/ros-groovy-bosch-common_binarydeb_oneiric_amd64/1/console).
I had the same error in the pre-release but I sloppily ignored it.

I agree that roscpp is not a system dependency but I also do not declare it as such. Any suggestions what might have gone wrong?

D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54476/jenkins-debian-building-fails:-rosdep-claims-that-roscpp-is-not-a-system-dependency/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue you are having is that you are missing ros_comm in your stack dependencies.  Which means that roscpp is not pulled in when satisfying installation dependencies.  Thus neither rospack nor rosdep can find roscpp when processing the package.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2013-02-18**:
Maybe this is a better fix. What also fixed it was to remove roscpp all together, it seems that there was no explicit dependencies on it.